# Git lists unchanged files , I'm confused

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm using TFS, Git and VS.
When I clone code from TFS, it lists so many changed files, but I just clone it, not do any changes.

When I try to checkout files, it doesn't work, files still in the 'changed' area. How to avoid this?

Comment: Is your issue solved? Did you try the method below?

Answer (score 0):

If your TFS repo is a Git one, make sure you first type (once)

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That would avoid Git itself to change the eol style (end of line) of *all* the files on checkout.
Then try to clone again and see if the changes are still there.